# How to solve this error with Mobx in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, mobx

I am trying to use Mobx to organize all of state in React Native App but I got error like 'Cannot read property "bindings" of null' in my Store below.

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class RestaurantStore {
 @observable
 name = 'コンビニ屋';

 @observable
 tag = 'ショッピング';

 @observable
 shortDescription = '＄10以上のお買い上げでスタンプ１個';
}

export default RestaurantStore;
```

Could you help me, please.

To add my package.json below.

```
 "dependencies": {
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
 "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.3.4",
 "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
 "expo": "^32.0.0",
 "firebase": "^5.8.1",
 "mobx": "^5.8.0",
 "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
 "react": "16.5.0",
 "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-    
  32.0.0.tar.gz",
 "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
 "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
 "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
 "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
},
 "devDependencies": {
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
 "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
 "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
 "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
 "directory": "^0.1.0",
 "eslint": "^5.12.0",
 "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
 "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
 "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
 "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.3",
 "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.0"
},
```

Comment: You should export a singleton object of your store. I don't know if this has to do with the error, but you should do `const store = new RestaurantStore()` and then `export default store`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
But I did what you  mentioned in my Home.js with Provider from Mobx.

Comment: Try the older syntax, probably could be due to the decorator syntax

Comment: your issue is babel related. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8575

Comment: I have added my package.json. Is anything wrong in babel?

Answer (score 0):

try this format

```
import { observable, action, computed, toJS , decorate} from "mobx";

class RestaurantStore{
  name = 'コンビニ屋';
  tag = 'ショッピング';
  shortDescription = '＄10以上のお買い上げでスタンプ１個';
}

export default decorate(RestaurantStore, {
  name: observable,
  tag: observable,
  shortDescription: observable
});
```